# Rails 5 Nested Form Image Upload, Cache and View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have two models; products and variations.  Variations form is nested in products form.  I am also using [Shrine](http://shrinerb.com/) file attachment gem to handle uploads.  My variations model has a name and an photo field.  When the photo field was part of my product model, it worked great; I could upload, get a preview and delete. Since moving it into a nested partial, I am getting all kinds `undefined methods` on my photo fields.  But as a test, I deleted everything in my nested partial and added only the file_field `<%= f.file_field :photo_one %>` and the file uploaded and persisted to the database, so I know the partial association is setup correctly.

**_form_html.erb**

```
...

<h4>Variations</h4>
<div class="row">
  <%= f.fields_for :variations do |variation| %>
    <%= render 'variation_fields', :f => variation %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add variation', f, :variations, :class => "btn btn--sm" %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= submit_tag 'Submit', class: 'btn btn--sm' %>
  </div>
</div>   
...
```

**_variation_field.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <%= f.label :name, 'Name' %>
                <%= f.text_field :name %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= f.label :photo_one, 'Photo One' %>
            <% if :photo_one.present? %>
                <div class="product-image">
                    <%= image_tag(@product.photo_one_url(:thumb)) %>
                    <div class="input-checkbox input-checkbox--switch">
                        <input name="product[remove_photo_one]" type="hidden" value="0">
                        <input id="checkbox-switch" type="checkbox" name="product[remove_photo_one]">
                        <label for="checkbox-switch"></label>
                    </div>
                    <span>Remove Image</span>
                </div>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :photo_one, value: @product.cached_photo_one_data %>
            <%= f.file_field :photo_one %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**model product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  include ImageUploader[:spec_sheet]

  has_many :categories
  has_many :variations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :variations, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories, allow_destroy: true
```

**model variation.rb**

```
class Variation < ApplicationRecord
    include ImageUploader[:photo_one]

    belongs_to :product
end
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
...
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(
      ...
      variations_attributes: [
        :id, 
        :name, 
        :position, 
        :photo_one,
        :remove_photo_one,
        :_destroy
      ],
  )
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Is you `@product` instantiated in the `products#action`?

   ```
   def action
       @product = Product.new(product_params)
   end
   ```
2. Pass the `@product` as local variable to the `partial`

   ```
   <%= render 'variation_fields', locals: { f: variation, product: @product %>
   ```

   then in your partial `_variation_field.html.erb`

   ```
   <%= image_tag(product.photo_one_url(:thumb)) %>
   ```

---

Update

Go in your console and test shrine

```
# no file is attached
photo.image #=> nil

# the assigned file is cached to temporary storage and written to `image_data` column
photo.image = File.open("waterfall.jpg")
photo.image      #=> #<Shrine::UploadedFile @data={...}>
photo.image_url  #=> "/uploads/cache/0sdfllasfi842.jpg"
photo.image_data #=> '{"id":"0sdfllasfi842.jpg","storage":"cache","metadata":{...}}'

# the cached file is promoted to permanent storage and saved to `image_data` column
photo.save
photo.image      #=> #<Shrine::UploadedFile @data={...}>
photo.image_url  #=> "/uploads/store/l02kladf8jlda.jpg"
photo.image_data #=> '{"id":"l02kladf8jlda.jpg","storage":"store","metadata":{...}}'

# the attached file is deleted with the record
photo.destroy
photo.image.exists? #=> false
```

read the `shrine` docs and test you methods in the console. Once you can run them there, you can build up the functionality. Also read the [documentation](http://shrinerb.com/rdoc/files/README_md.html#label-Attachment)

Comment: I still get the error `undefined local variable or method product for #< <Class:0x007fe5e6f04c08>:0x007fe5d5d95ba8> Did you mean?  @product`

Comment: @StudioRooster `#< <Class:0x007fe5e6f04c08>:0x007fe5d5d95ba8>` is the `product` class?!? So the problem is your `.photo_one_url(:thumb)` method. Make sure you setted correctly shrine. read the updated post.

Comment: I updated my post @StudioRooster . I will not follow this post anymore .. Sorry. Good luck with your app